# iOS get destination url before uiwebview goBack

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I set a custom button that executes a goBack method of uiwebview. However, I need then to get destination url when this button is pressed. How could I acces to first position of navigation history? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`
and store the URL from the NSURLRequest in an instance variable. Then simply access this variable in your goBack method. If you're multiple navigation steps in, use an array to store each subsequent request and then just access the object at index 0 to get the original URL.

Comment: I believe that UIWebView maintains navigation history. Is there an API  with which I could access the history?